# priority_queue.top() does not return the right object

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a priority queue to return the object 'Bytetree' with lowest 'count'. Therefore i have implemented an bool operator > function in my object. But that does not seem to work, i get objects based on something else

i have tried implmenting operator< as a friend or member function and with countless modifications, but it seems never to get called at all. why not?

```
class Bytetree{         
public:
bool leaf;
unsigned char byt;
int count;
Bytetree* child0;
Bytetree* child1;

    Bytetree(unsigned char c): byt(c), count(0), child0(nullptr), child1(nullptr), leaf(true){};
    Bytetree(Bytetree* c0, Bytetree* c1): child0(c0), child1(c1), count(c0->count+c1->count), leaf(false){};

         bool operator>(const Bytetree & right) {
    std::cout << "called at all" ;
    return count > right.count;
         }

[...]
 }
```

main

...

```
 std::priority_queue<Bytetree*, std::deque<Bytetree*>, std::greater<Bytetree*> > que;
for (int i = 0; i<WORDLENGTH; i++){

    que.push(mywc.wordar[i]);
    //  mywc.wordar[i]->print();
}

while(que.size()>=2){
    Bytetree* bt0= que.top();
    que.pop();
    Bytetree* bt1= que.top();
    que.pop();

    que.push(new Bytetree(bt0, bt1));
}
```

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: You're comparing the pointers, not the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `std::greater<Bytetree *>`, but you have declared `operator >`  on `Bytetree`, not on `Bytetree *`.

Comment: ...so it's sorting numerically by address of the bytetree, not by the `count`